# How do i let the user add a string to an array, while there is already existing strings in it? (Windows forms)

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I started doing C# for school about 5 weeks ago, and i started with knowing absolutely nothing about it. So sorry if i put something in a incorrect way .

Basically i need to let the user add a string to an array, while other strings already exist inside of it and then they need to show up in a label.
(basically a system where you can add employees to a list by using arrays)

this is what i've got right now:

```
    private void UserLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this is the Label
    {

    }

    private void UserInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is the TextBox
    {

    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is the Button
    {
        string[] Users = new string[10];
        Users[0] = "Jake";
        Users[1] = "Cole";
        Users[2] = "Petra";
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] Users = new string[10];
        Users[0] = "Jake";
        Users[1] = "Cole";
        Users[2] = "Petra";
        UserLabel.Text = Users[0] + "\r\n" + Users[1] + "\r\n" + Users[2] + "\r\n" + Users[3] + "\r\n" + Users[4] + "\r\n" + Users[5] + "\r\n" + Users[6] + "\r\n" + Users[7] + "\r\n" + Users[8] + "\r\n" + Users[9];
    }
```

My teacher told me that I had to do something with an i >, =, or < so that it checks all the strings, looking for a string that's blank and then fills that one with the text from the textbox. But i can't find anything about it.

So how do i do this?

(This is for a school exercise.)
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will need to do is check each element in the array, this can be done with a `for` loop and an `if` statement.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    if (CheckSomething(array[i])) { 
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

As this is a school question people on Stack Overflow might be less likely to give you the right answer to a whole coding challenge, and only to specific questions about about implementation. There's lots of stuff out there online, so I would suggest do some reading, and if you have any specific questions, come back and ask.

Happy coding!